# Flip/switch values in two columns if value in a third column is positive or negative

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to swap/switch the values in two columns if a value in a third column is negative.

```
id <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
effect <- c("A", "C", "G", "A", "G")
non_effect <- c("C", "A", "T", "C", "C")
variable1 <- c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X")
variable2 <- c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")
value <-c("0.2", "-0.1", "-0.3", "0.5", "0.8")

df <- data.frame(id,effect,non_effect,variable1,variable2,value)
```

I would get this as a data.frame

```
id effect non_effect variable1 variable2 value
1  A      C          X         Y         0.2
2  C      A          X         Y        -0.1
3  G      T          X         Y        -0.3
4  A      C          X         Y         0.5
5  G      C          X         Y         0.8
```

what I want is:

```
id effect non_effect variable1 variable2 value
1  A      C          X         Y         0.2
2  A      C          X         Y         0.1
3  T      G          X         Y         0.3
4  A      C          X         Y         0.5
5  G      C          X         Y         0.8
```

Comment: `df%>% ifelse(value<0, operation_switch_columns, otherwise)` I guess this would be the kick start but I don't know the operation to switch columns

Comment: `eff <- df$effect; neff <- df$non_effect; df$effect <- ifelse(value <0, eff, neff); df$non_effect <- ifelse(value <0, neff, eff);`. The way out is through the door... why will noone use this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df %>%
  transform(effect = ifelse(value < 0, non_effect, effect),
            non_effect = ifelse(value < 0, effect, non_effect), 
            value = abs(as.numeric(value)))

# A tibble: 5 x 6
  id    effect non_effect variable1 variable2 value
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
1 1     A      C          X         Y           0.2
2 2     A      C          X         Y           0.1
3 3     T      G          X         Y           0.3
4 4     A      C          X         Y           0.5
5 5     G      C          X         Y           0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Set to `data.table`, and change the columns in-place, when value<0

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[,value:=as.numeric(value)]
df[value<0, c("effect", "non_effect", "value"):=list(non_effect,effect,abs(value))]
```

Output:

```
   id effect non_effect variable1 variable2 value
1:  1      A          C         X         Y   0.2
2:  2      A          C         X         Y   0.1
3:  3      T          G         X         Y   0.3
4:  4      A          C         X         Y   0.5
5:  5      G          C         X         Y   0.8
```

Similar approach in base R

```
df$value = as.numeric(df$value)
df[df$value<0,c("effect","non_effect")] <- df[df$value<0, c("non_effect","effect")] 
df$value = abs(df$value)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
id <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
effect <- c("A", "C", "G", "A", "G")
non_effect <- c("C", "A", "T", "C", "C")
variable1 <- c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X")
variable2 <- c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")
value <-c("0.2", "-0.1", "-0.3", "0.5", "0.8")

df <- data.frame(id,effect,non_effect,variable1,variable2,value) 

df %>% 
  mutate(
    value = as.numeric(value),
    effect1 = ifelse(value < 0, non_effect, effect),
    non_effect1 = ifelse(value < 0, effect, non_effect
    ),
    value = abs(value)
  ) %>% 
  select(id, effect = effect1, non_effect = non_effect1, variable1, variable2, value)
```

Output:

```
id effect non_effect variable1 variable2 value
1      A          C         X         Y   0.2
2      A          C         X         Y   0.1
3      T          G         X         Y   0.3
4      A          C         X         Y   0.5
5      G          C         X         Y   0.8
```